# Is there a conclusive correlation between viscosity and surface tension?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, viscosity

I'm working on a project and I need to know if the viscosity effects on the surface tension or not?

Comment: No, they arise from totally different mechanisms. It's possible you'll find specific systems where viscosity and surface tension are correlated, but in general there is no correlation.

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

$\mathbf{\text{Viscosity}}$: it arises from cohesive forces between the (similar) molecules & the momentum exchange between the adjacent/consecutive layers of a fluid.

$\mathbf{\text{Surface tension}}$: it arises only from the cohesive forces between the similar molecules at the free surface & the molecules inside of a fluid

Comment: So aren't both dependent upon the strength of the cohesive forces?

Comment: So, What's my answer??